# If $P(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+a_{n-2}z^{n-2}+...+a_1z+a_o$ a polynomial whose coefficients are all real.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $P(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+a_{n-2}z^{n-2}+...+a_1z+a_o$ a polynomial who's coefficients are all real.

Explain why if $z_1$ is a root of $P$, then $\bar{z_1}$ is also a root.

And give an example as to why the contrary is false if the coefficients of $P$ are not all real.

Comment: Can you give us some insight into what you have tried? What do you know about this? Right now it looks like a homework exercise that you are just trying to get the answer for instead of trying to find understanding and having actually tried the problem.